# Copy textfield and dropdown and add to textarea

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onclick, copy, textfield

I'm having a problem copying the value of a text field and adding that value along with the value of a dropdown to a text area.   when I click the button I can get the values from dropdowns to copy over but when i try and copy a dropdown value and a textfield value it won't work and I get an 'Uncaught TypeError:  Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined.  Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copy() {
    var a = document.getElementById("qty");
    var b = document.getElementById("text-two");
    var text = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value + "---" + b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;   
    var out = document.getElementById("textarea");
    out.value += text + "\n";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming a is drop down and b is textbox)

```
var text = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value + "---" + b.value;
```

or assuming(assuming b is drop down and a is textbox)

```
var text = a.value + "---" + b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
```